# Render Component every time it's get clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a List of country that shows name and id.
I want to able to edit the countries, so i add it edit button for each row. the structure of component is like :

```
ListComponent
 -- Edit Component // will show a modal
 --- Modal Component
 ---- Form Component
```

I should fill the form whenever modal is open, now the question is : 
which life cycle method should i use to fill the form ?

`componentDidMount` only fire once.

`componentDidUpdate` won't trigger on first call and will trigger afterward.

**Code :**

```
  componentDidMount(prevProps, prevState) {
      if(this.props.status == 'update') {
        this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
          isForeign: this.props.country.isForeign,
          name: this.props.country.name,
        });
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle start AND updates in a class component, you have to use both lifecycle methods. That’s a big reason why React implemented hooks for functional components, to avoid the redundancy.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: do you have any suggestion for this kinda stuff ?

Comment: Try repeating your code in componentDidUpdate. It seems, though, that you would be better served controlling this form from the parent component. In the parent component you could simply control this all with state instead of having to check the props with life cycles and then doing callbacks to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentWillReceiveProps`

> componentWillReceiveProps: Executed when particular prop updates to
>   trigger state transitions.

Small example from my code base

```
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if (this.props.userId !== nextProps.userId) {
                    const url = `${ROLE_API}/${nextProps.userId}`;
                    Get(url).then(res => {
                            this.setState({rolesName: res.data.rolesName, 
                             currentUserRoles: res.data.currentUserRoles,
                             userId: res.data.userId});
                    });
            }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but at first click it won't trigger but after second click it's triggerd